# Getting value of three consecutive elements in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, cgi, url-parameters

I have a large array, `h`, that contains several instances of a parameter called `startingParam`, which is always followed by two other parameters that are related but not always the same. I need to look for every instance of `startingParam` in the array, and push it and the next two parameters into a separate array, `holdingArray`.

The following code is not working, due to the fact that I am very new to Ruby. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach the problem?

```
h.each do |param|
    if param == 'startingParam'
        holdingArray << h.[param],
        holdingArray << h.[param + 1],
        holdingArray << h.[param + 2]
    end
end
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a few problems. For starters, you can't subscript arrays by doing `h.[anything]`, and you are also subscripting based on the value (and not the index). You are also checking to see if the parameter matches the literal string "starting_param" and not its value. So what I expect you want is the following:

```
h.each_with_index do |param, index|
  if param == startingParam
    holdingArray << h[index]
    holdingArray << h[index+1]
    holdingArray << h[index+2]
  end
end
```

You'll also note that if the item is in the last two slots of the array, this will wrap around and grab items from the beginning of the array (due to how Ruby handles array subscripts being out of bounds).

Comment: So, if I use `if param == startingParam` it will attempt to find the *name* of the `startingParam`, and if I use `if param == "startingParam"` it will look for the *value* of `startingParam`?

Comment: `param == startingParam` checks the value of the variable `param` for equality with the value of the variable `startingParam`, while `param == "startingParam"` checks the value of the variable `param` for equality with the literal string `"startingParam"`

Comment: Ruby doesn't wrap around when you index it with an out of bounds value, it just returns `nil`...

Answer (score 4):

You can grab the chunks using `#slice_before`:

```
arr = ['startingParam', 1, 2, 'startingParam', 3, 4]

arr.slice_before('startingParam')
# => [['startingParam', 1, 2], ['startingParam', 3, 4]]
```

If you created the original data structure, you may want to re-consider your design, however.

Comment: That's the prob... I don't have access to the data design.

Answer (score 3):

Functional approach:

```
>> ary = ['hello', 'startingParam', 1, 2, 'xyz', 'startingParam', 3, 4, 'bye']    
>> ary.each_cons(3).select { |v, *vs| v == "startingParam" }.flatten(1)
=> ["startingParam", 1, 2, "startingParam", 3, 4]
```

Comment: One of the nice things about functional programming is that it's often more declarative - you write what you want done, rather than how you're doing it.

Comment: @Andrew: As some schemer said: "Functional programming is like describing your problem to a mathematician. Imperative programming is like giving instructions to an idiot." :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the range slicing operation (I've changed the varnames slightly since camelcasing is bad style in ruby)

```
h.each_with_index do |param, index|
  if param == starting_param
     holding_array.push(h[index..index+2])
  end
end
```